# Does Allah command us to view the sacrifice of animal on Eid-Ul-Adha?

Tags: animals, sacrifice, eid-ul-adha, udhiyyah

On the occasion of Eid-Ul-Adha, has Allah commanded the Muslims to view the sacrifice of the animal on that day?
Let's say I have an animal that will be sacrificed on Eid-Ul-Adha and I am not comfortable slaughtering the animal even though I am fit and fine, then does Allah command me to view the slaughtering of the animal? If I am fit and fine, then am I obliged to slaughter the animal myself?
Please clarify !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not essential to perform the sacrifice with your own hand, nor to be present at the time of the sacrifice. However it is recommended to do it yourself, or at least to be present near it and watch it.

The Prophet ﷺ sacrificed 100 camels, 63 with his own hand and then he told Ali Ibn Abi Talib to slaughter the remainder ([Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1218a), [Nasai](https://sunnah.com/nasai:4419)) and he also sacrificed on behalf of his wives ([Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5559)) etc. And it is claimed the Prophet ﷺ told Fatimah to be present when the sacrifice was done on her behalf ([Sunan al-Kubra Bayhaqi](https://shamela.ws/book/7861/21804)).

**Ref:**

> الذي يرجع إلى من عليه التضحية فالأفضل أن يذبح بنفسه إن قدر عليه لأنه قربة فمباشرتها بنفسه أفضل من توليتها غيره كسائر القربات ... وإذا لم يذبح بنفسه  ... يستحب أن يحضر الذبح
>
> <sup>— [Badaa'i' as-Sanaa'i'](https://shamela.ws/book/8183/1212#p1)</sup>

> وإن ذبحها بيده كان أفضل ... . فإن استناب فيها، جاز ... ويستحب أن يحضر ذبحها
>
> <sup>— [al-Mughni](https://shamela.ws/book/6910/7077#p1)</sup>

> وأن يذبحها بنفسه، وإلا فليشهدها
>
> <sup>— [Minhaj al-Talibin](https://shamela.ws/book/12096/354) \ ([sharah](https://shamela.ws/book/11444/2852))</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Just a quick spin-off question, did Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) started the sunnah of Ibraheem after the complete revelation of Quran?

Comment: Comments are not for spinoff questions.